# Difference between Display and Shell

Tags: java, swt

A typical SWT sample code looks like the following code:

```
final Display display = Display.getDefault();
final Shell shell = createMyShell(display);
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
    }
}
```

What is the difference between `Display` and `Shell`?
If multiple windows have to be shown, does each one need an own loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you have to show multiple windows (shells), you must have a loop for each one.

But there is only one [`Display`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html) object in an application that you need to create.

Comment: Thanks, so the `Display` is just an instance to the underlying graphic system and the `Shell` is the window, right?

Comment: Do I understand it right, that one `while`-loop for the whole application would be sufficient as long as there is at least one undisposed `shell`?

Comment: No, there must be a loop for each shell. It keeps the shell open. If you only call `shell.open()`, you'll see that it opens, and closes right the next second.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.  You only need to run the `Display` read/dispatch loop once to process all the open shells.  If you were to open many shells serially, you would indeed need to run the display loop each time.  But if you were to open multiple shells at once, you only need a single event loop...

Comment: sorry for the down vote, but the answer is misleading. Usually you have only one event dispatch loop. That's common in many UI frameworks (ie AWT). In fact if you try to run the dispatch loop in multiple threads it will not work in some platforms (macOS): http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fswt_threading.htm
The answer from @ChrisWhoCodes should be marked as the right for this question

Answer (score 6):

You can have multiple shells with a single Display and a single while loop handing event dispatch. Create the display, create the Shell(s) from the Display, and then start the single UI event dispatcher loop. See http://www.chrisnewland.com/av/111/swt-best-practice-single-display-multiple-shells

Answer (score 1):

ChrisWhoCodes is quite correct. The following code implements his model.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MultipleShells {
  public MultipleShells(Display display) {
    Shell[]             shells;
    MainWindows         mainWindow;
    mainWindow = new MainWindows(display, "Shell 1");    
    mainWindow = new MainWindows(display, "Shell 2");

    while (!display.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        shells = display.getShells();
        if (shells.length == 0)
          break;
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    MultipleShells mainApp = new MultipleShells(display);
    display.dispose();
  }
}  

class MainWindows {
    protected MainWindows(Display parent, String title) {  
    Shell               mainShell;
    mainShell = new Shell(parent);
    mainShell.setText(title);
    mainShell.open();
  }  
}
```